# Why is it possible to create a object from QWidget without including it at the beginning of the C++ program

Tags: c++, qt

This is a simple Qt C++ program that creates a GUI. I'm a student, also I'm not that familiar with C++ than Java. In the code showing bellow, there is a window object-reference of class `QWidget` called `*window` which didn't have included at the beginning of the code. As far as I know, all included widgets are under QWidget(QSlider & QSpinBox). What is the base class of QWidget. (if there is a base class between QObject and QWidget)? Why is it possible to create a object from QWidget without including it? Why is that `whole object` of `QWidget base class` displayed as a window if those other Widget classes are under it(see the image bellow).

image from [C++-GUI-Programming-with-Qt-4-1st-ed ebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaBFf.jpg)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QSpinBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QWidget *window = new QWidget;
  window->setWindowTitle("select your age");


  QSlider *slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
  QSpinBox *spin = new QSpinBox;
  slider->setRange(0, 130);
  spin->setRange(0, 130);

  QObject::connect( spin, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), slider, SLOT(setValue(int)) );
  QObject::connect( slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), spin, SLOT(setValue(int)) );

  spin->setValue(30);

  QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

  layout->addWidget(spin);
  layout->addWidget(slider);
  window->setLayout(layout);

  window->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#details ? "A widget that is not embedded in a parent widget is called a window."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#details):

> The widget is the atom of the user interface. (...) A widget is
>   clipped by its parent and by the widgets in front of it.
>
> A widget that is not embedded in a parent widget is called a window.
>   (...)
>
> A widget without a parent widget is always an independent window
>   (top-level widget).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The question was: "why can you use `QWidget` without having an `#include <QWidget>` in the code."

Answer (score 4):

`QSlider` inherits from `QAbstractSlider` which itself inherits from `QWidget`. So the inclusion of `QSlider` indirectly includes `QWidget`, allowing you to create one. `QSpinBox`, as any other widget, also inherits from `QWidget`.

As explained [in the doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#details) :

> A widget without a parent widget is always an independent window
>   (top-level widget).

So the `QWidget *window` actually creates a window, with a title bar and all.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the base class of QWidget.

[QWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) inherits from QObject and QPaintDevice.

> Why is it possible to create a object from QWidget without including it?

I'd guess that `<QSlider>` and / or `<QSpinBox>` include `<QWidget>`. Yes, for the sake of the example it would probably be "cleaner" if there were an explicit `#include <QWidget>` as well, but apparently it is not necessary.

> Why that whole QWidget displayed as a window if those other Widget classes are under it.

Sorry but I am not sure what you are asking here, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

*What is the base class of QWidget. (if there is a base class between QObject and QWidget)?*

I don't know. QWidget is the basic GUI class. By that I mean that all other GUI classes have to derive from it. So it really doesn't matter much what is above it in the hierarchy chain.

*Why is it possible to create a object from QWidget without including it?*

By this I presume that you mean #include the QWidget.h. QSpinBox and QSlider derive from it so I presume that their headers include QWidget.h. Including is transitive.

*Why that whole QWidget displayed as a window if those other Widget classes are under it.*
This is really unclear. It would make no sense for a widget to be a window if it did not contain other widgets.